# Getting an error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React by following a video by Clever Programmer
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUxrDcITyjg&list=PLvmRwCtZ6YKRBCjKGNEbmOd816fgvptZc&index=17&t=20s)

However, towards the end I am finding an error which is not openly reported in comments or threads.
I have localised it to the following file "Chat.js" which contains the below code.

My question is: What could be tripping the error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.".

Advice or solution would be great, but if solved, please provide reasoning as I will need to learn why it was not working!

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Chat.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider.js";


import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  AttachFile,
  InsertEmoticon,
  Mic,
  SearchOutlined,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import MoreVert from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";
import db from "./firebase";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

function Chat() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [seed, setSeed] = useState("");
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));

      db.collection('rooms')
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot =>
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        );
    }
  }, [roomId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSeed(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
  }, [roomId]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("You typed: >>>", input);

    db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId).collection('messages').add({
      message: input,
      user: user.displayName,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })

    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <div className="chat__header">
        <Avatar src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg`} />

        <div className="chat__headerInfo">
          <h3>{roomName}</h3>
          <p>Last seen...</p>
        </div>

        <div className="chat__headerRight">
          <IconButton>
            <SearchOutlined />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <AttachFile />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVert />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* The div "chat__body" incorporates the entire message structure  */}
      <div className="chat__body">
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <p className={`chat__message ${message.name === user.displayName && "chat__receiver"}`}>
            <span className="chat__name">{message.name}</span>
            {message.message}
            <span className="chat__timeStamp">
              {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}
            </span>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="chat__footer">
        <InsertEmoticon />
        <form>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Type a message"
            type="text"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">
            Send a message
          </button>
        </form>
        <Mic />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Comment: `p.chat__message` needs the key

Comment: This answer has already been posted on Stack Overflow many times. Also the docs as @RobinZigmond just posted clearly show why you need unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages.map` is returning a list, and each item in it must have a unique key value that identifies it.

Either from an id from the current item

```js
messages.map((message) => (
<p key={message.id} className...
```

or the current index

```js
messages.map((message, i) => (
<p key={i} className...
```